# How can I disable the 'application search' view that appears after logging in, on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, login, 22.04

When I login to Ubuntu 22.04, the view defaults to this 'application search' view.

Is there any way I can disable this and just go straight to the 'desktop' view.  Also, what is this view called? Not knowing what it's called may have hindered my ability to search, in case this question was already answered.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called overview mode (the search-bar that appears when you hit the super-key.)

Looks like there is an extension to disable this exact behavior at startup: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/

Information about install gnome extensions can be found here:
https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/

Hope this helps

Comment: Overview! Thanks this got me on the right path.  I think this is the right answer. It didn't work for me because of the Dash to Panel extension so I'll add another answer for that one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the Dash to Panel extension installed, which doesn't work with the No Overview extension.  Instead, the Dash to Panel extension has its own setting to disable this behavior. Dash To Panel Settings, Behavior Tab, "Disable Show Overview on Startup"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a different solution that isn't based on shell extensions (and thus should be more resilient to newer gnome versions and future incompatibilities).

This solution can be implemented system-wide or affecting just a user, depending on where the files are put.  OBS: Please notice that the first file must be made executable with `chmod 755 /usr/libexec/no-overview-at-startup` or `chmod 755 ${HOME}/bin/no-overview-at-startup` depending if you will use the system-wide or user-specific approach.

**First the files to be used if you chose the system-wide approach:**

**File 1**: `/usr/libexec/no-overview-at-startup`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

# Monitoring time in tenths of seconds
MTIME=50
for ((i=0; i<${MTIME}; i++)); do
  read -r DUMMY DUMMY IS_OVERVIEW <<< "$(dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell --type=method_call /org/gnome/Shell org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.gnome.Shell string:OverviewActive)"
  if [[ "${IS_OVERVIEW}" = "true" ]] ; then
    /usr/bin/dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell --type=method_call /org/gnome/Shell org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:org.gnome.Shell string:OverviewActive variant:boolean:false
    exit
  fi
  sleep 0.1
done
```

**File 2**: `/etc/xdg/autostart/no-overview-at-startup.desktop`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/libexec/no-overview-at-startup
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=No Overview at Start-up
Name=No Overview at Start-up
Comment[en_US]=Disable overview mode right after login
Comment=Disable overview mode right after login
```

**Alternatively, in order for this to affect only a user, the files should be placed in different directories and a change in File 2 is required:**

File 1 location: `${HOME}/bin/no-overview-at-startup`

File 2 location: `${HOME}/.config/autostart/no-overview-at-startup.desktop`

**Important:** File 2 must have the line beginning with `EXEC=...` changed to `EXEC=${HOME}/bin/no-overview-at-startup`

OBS: Finally, I use Fedora and consequently have no experience building Ubuntu/deb packages, but if you are using Fedora I've also provided a `.spec` file for building an RPM in this other thread with a similar question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717123/how-to-disable-gnome-workspace-selection-at-login):